# innovaeditor - dynamic add on link click

Tags: jquery

i am stucked with this wysiwyg editor http://www.innovastudio.com/.

I am trying to add multiple editors on page with click on link. Take a look at my code.

```
var times_clicked = 1;
    $("#add_more_stuff").click(function(){
        times_clicked++;
        var a = times_clicked;
        console.log(a);
        $('<textarea id="editor'+a+'" name="lesson"></textarea>').appendTo('body');
        $('<script>var oEdit'+a+' = new InnovaEditor("oEdit'+a+'"); oEdit'+a+'.REPLACE("editor'+a+'");<\/script>').appendTo($("#e"));
    });
```

This adds one editor and whole page blows!!!
If this can not be done with this editor is there any other editor that supports this, dynamic adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got into this problem too. You must use a div replacement in order to make it work. Also, note that for this to work, the oEdit must be declared in page scope. It will not work if you declare the variable in a function. If you declare it in a function, you have to add the refernce to browser's window object for example:

```
window["oEdit1"] = new InnovaEditor("oEdit1");
window["oEdit1"].REPLACE("textarea id", "myEditor");
```

Now here is your modified code (kind of ugly way to do it, but for the sake of your example):

```
var times_clicked = 1;
$("#add_more_stuff").click(function(){
    times_clicked++;
    var a = times_clicked;
    console.log(a);
    $('<textarea id="editor'+a+'" name="lesson"></textarea><div id="div_editor'+a+'"></div>').appendTo('body');
    $('<script>window["oEdit"'+a+'"] = new InnovaEditor("oEdit'+a+'");window["oEdit"'+a+'"].REPLACE("editor'+a+'","div_editor'+a+'");<\/script>').appendTo('body');
});
```

.. and that's it, it should work this way...